# Custom CardStackUI making the last card also just like others

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-cardview

We are using [CardStackUI](https://github.com/mutualmobile/CardStackUI) for one of our screens. Is it possible to make the last card also just like others? We want to show a heading and on a click show the full card. How to do this?

Comment: for that you have to download the lib and do some changes in the lib code for your customization

Comment: Thanks for the help